# Embedding Python DLL in Lua & exposing functions

Tags: python, dll, lua, wrapper, embedding

Is it possible to embed the Python DLL to a Lua program? And expose functions to it? I've also thought about a wrapper library, if Lua can't handle this on its own. May there be already a project trying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick googling finds [Lunatic Python](http://labix.org/lunatic-python), a two-way Python-Lua bridge.